# Loading DOM from HTML: How does a HTML parser know when empty element ends

Tags: html, html-parsing

In XML, empty elements has a corresponding tag marked with />. But that is not present in HTML. So do a HTML parser have a finite list of elements that can be empty. What if such an element has an end tag?

Comment: This is documented in the [HTML5 ('living') specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/); a bit drudgy, but all there. Also note that some elements, eg. BR have 'no content', which is different from 'empty content'.

Comment: @user2864740 "A thead element's end tag can be omitted if the thead element is immediately followed by a tbody or tfoot element." Hmm, that is worse than a list of elements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are tags in html which have a closing tag and one's which don't have one.And it's more confusing after the introduction of HTML5. After a lot of research Here's what i found so far. I hope you'll understand :)

> do a HTML parser have a finite list of elements that can be empty.
>
> Answer : Yes, HTML parsers have finite list of empty elements. The parser have certain rules for parsing and will ignore the empty tags.

These are the elements that can be empty. (Source :- [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element)

```
<link>
<track>
<param>
<area>
<command>
<col>
<base>
<meta>
<hr>
<source>
<img>
<keygen>
<br>
<wbr>
<colgroup> when the span is present
<input>
```

In HTML, using a closing tag on an empty element is invalid. For example, `<input type="text"></input>` is invalid HTML and the parser will ignore those tags.

> "Empty elements (void elements)" were introduced to HTML by mistake: presentational
> markup crept into the language, contrary to the spirit of SGML, and
> with some strange syntactic implications. This fundamental error has
> caused some technical problems like an unintended discrepancy between
> HTML and XHTML, causing surprises in validation. More importantly, it
> illustrates the implications of the decision to make HTML formally,
> and only formally, an "SGML application". "Empty elements" are more
> than they look like.

Source (worth reading) : [cs.tut.fi empty elements research paper](https://www.cs.tut.fi/%7Ejkorpela/html/empty.html#html) )

> What if such an element has an end tag?
>
> The parser will ignore  the element which has an end tag and it will consume the next element or character for parsing. And the parser will throw an ignored syntax error

Read This w3c article, It's about HTML empty elements (void elements) [W3C Link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements)

Article about empty elements by  [456bereastreet](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201005/void_empty_elements_and_self-closing_start_tags_in_html/)

Color glare article on empty elements [Colorglare link](http://www.colorglare.com/2014/02/03/to-close-or-not-to-close.html)

Answer (score 4):

> So do a HTML parser have a finite list of elements that can be empty.

Yes. HTML parsers know the rules for HTML, and those rules say which elements have no end tag (or optional end tags).

For example:

> > A start tag whose tag name is one of: "area", "br", "embed", "img", "keygen", "wbr"
> >     
> > ...
> >     Insert an HTML element for the token. Immediately pop the current node off the stack of open elements.

---

> What if such an element has an end tag?

Then it is invalid and — like any other end tag for a tag which is not open — the tag is discarded when the parser reaches it.

> > If node is not the current node, then this is a parse error.

Comment: You should include the source you're quoting.